Issues with Loading Pretrained Model and File Locking in DeepSpeed and Hugging Face Transformers
I am currently working on a project involving the MobileVLM model, using Hugging Face Transformers library for loading pretrained models. I encountered an issue while running my script on a SLURM cluster.
Exception ignored in atexit callback: <function matmul_ext_update_autotune_table at 0x7fbb99fa4ca0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/transformer/inference/triton/matmul_ext.py", line 444, in matmul_ext_update_autotune_table
    fp16_matmul._update_autotune_table()
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/transformer/inference/triton/matmul_ext.py", line 421, in _update_autotune_table
    TritonMatmul._update_autotune_table(__class__.__name__ + "_2d_kernel", __class__._2d_kernel)
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/transformer/inference/triton/matmul_ext.py", line 150, in _update_autotune_table
    cache_manager.put(autotune_table)
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/deepspeed/ops/transformer/inference/triton/matmul_ext.py", line 66, in put
    with FileLock(self.lock_path):
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/filelock/_api.py", line 297, in __enter__
    self.acquire()
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/filelock/_api.py", line 255, in acquire
    self._acquire()
  File "/public/home/swun-caiy2/miniconda3/envs/mobilevlm/lib/python3.10/site-packages/filelock/_unix.py", line 48, in _acquire
    raise NotImplementedError(msg) from exception
NotImplementedError: FileSystem does not appear to support flock; user SoftFileLock instead

Here is the relevant part of my SLURM script:
from scripts.inference import inference_once
import torch
# model_path = "mtgv/MobileVLM-1.7B" # finetune

model_path = "/public/home/swun-caiy2/wensm/mobilevlm-v2/MobileVLM-main/mtgv"
image_file = "assets/samples/my_book.jpg"
# prompt_str = "who are you?\nIgnore the content of uploading pictures when answering questions."
prompt_str = "What is the title of this book?"
# (or) What is the title of this book?
# (or) Is this book related to Education & Teaching?

torch.cuda.set_device(0)

args = type('Args', (), {
    "model_path": model_path,
    "image_file": image_file,
    "prompt": prompt_str,
    "conv_mode": "v1",
    "temperature": 0, 
    "top_p": None,
    "num_beams": 1,
    "max_new_tokens": 512,
    "load_8bit": False,
    "load_4bit": False,
})()

inference_once(args)

How can I resolve the file locking issue on a file system that does not support flock?

I am running into the same issue and am not sure how to resolve it.

If you have a directory somewhere that does support file locking, you can change the environment variable for the cache directory to that directory, e.g.:
$ export HF_HOME="/path/to/directory/with/file/locking"

